# Solucionado - Menu Responsivo, Evento Drop down via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia!

Estou tendo alguns problemas com o JS do meu menu responsivo.

Ocorre que, ao efetuar ao ativar a função responsiva da página, o mesmo vira um único menu, até ai tudo bem, porém, ao clicar nele, ele já trás todos os submenus expandidos!

Gostaria que o mesmo trouxesse cada um oculto, e ao clicar, expandisse aquela seção.

Exemplo!

:MENU: 
BASICO 
FINANCEIRO

Ao clicar em basico...

:MENU: 
BASICO 
.CADASTROS 
.CONSULTAS 
FINANCEIRO

Ao clicar em cadastros...

:MENU: 
BASICO 
.CADASTROS 
..Clientes 
..Produtos 
.CONSULTAS 
FINANCEIRO

Se clicar nos Nodes principais, ele expande seus filhos e fecha os filhos dos outros.

O Problema é que quando abro, ele já trás tudo expandido, exemplo:

:MENU: 
BASICO 
.CADASTROS 
..Clientes 
..Produtos 
.CONSULTAS 
..Clientes 
..Produtos 
FINANCEIRO 
.Cadastros 
..Contas

Isso deixa o menu muito grande, e atrapalha a navegação no mesmo!

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu_inc').prepend('<div id="indicatorContainer"><div id="pIndicator"><div id="cIndicator"></div></div></div>');
    var activeElement = $('#menu_inc>ul>li:first');

    $('#menu_inc>ul>li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        activeElement = $(this);
      }
    });

    var posLeft = activeElement.position().left;
    var elementWidth = activeElement.width();
    posLeft = posLeft + elementWidth / 2 - 6;
    if (activeElement.hasClass('has-sub')) {
      posLeft -= 6;
    }

    $('#menu_inc #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
    var element, leftPos, indicator = $('#menu_inc pIndicator');

    $("#menu_inc>ul>li").hover(function() {
      element = $(this);
      var w = element.width();
      if ($(this).hasClass('has-sub')) {
        leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 12;
      } else {
        leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 6;
      }

      $('#menu_inc #pIndicator').css('left', leftPos);
    }, function() {
      $('#menu_inc #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
    });

    $('#menu_inc>ul').prepend('<li id="menu-button"><a>Menu</a></li>');
    $("#menu-button").click(function() {
      if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
      } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#menu_inc {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  height: 44px;
  background: #b70303;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* W3C */
  width: auto;
}
#menu_inc ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
#menu_inc > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #b70303;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* W3C */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 500;
}
#menu_inc:after,
#menu_inc > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu_inc.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#menu_inc.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#menu_inc.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu_inc > ul > #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#menu_inc ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 32px;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#menu_inc li.has-sub::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li.has-sub::after {
  /*  Seta do menu Principal*/
  right: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #FFF;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li:hover::after {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#indicatorContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#pIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transition: left .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left .25s ease;
  -o-transition: left .25s ease;
  transition: left .25s ease;
}
#cIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  top: -12px;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
#menu_inc ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#menu_inc ul ul ul {
  top: 37px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu_inc.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu_inc.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li a {
  /* Sub Menus - Fazer shadow*/
  width: 130px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}
#menu_inc.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li:hover > a {
  /* Submenu selecionado*/
  background: #8B0000;
  color: #FFF;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li:last-child > a,
#menu_inc ul ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: '';
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 30px;
}
#menu_inc.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease, right 0.2s ease;
}
#menu_inc.align-right ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#menu_inc.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #menu_inc {
    width: auto;
  }
  #menu_inc.align-center ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #menu_inc.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #menu_inc ul {
    width: auto;
  }
  #menu_inc .submenuArrow,
  #menu_inc #indicatorContainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu_inc > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  #menu_inc > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #menu_inc li,
  #menu_inc > ul > li {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul,
  #menu_inc ul ul ul,
  #menu_inc ul > li:hover > ul,
  #menu_inc ul ul > li:hover > ul,
  #menu_inc.align-right ul ul,
  #menu_inc.align-right ul ul ul,
  #menu_inc.align-right ul > li:hover > ul,
  #menu_inc.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
  #menu_inc ul .has-sub::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu_inc ul li a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul li a {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 35px;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  #menu_inc.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul li:hover > a {
    background: none;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 50px;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 65px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 80px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 95px;
  }
  #menu_inc > ul > #menu-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #menu_inc #menu-button > a {
    padding: 14px 20px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul.open li,
  #menu_inc > ul.open > li {
    display: block;
  }
  #menu_inc > ul.open > li#menu-button > a {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.1);
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu_inc #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  #menu_inc #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
    right: 20px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul.open #menu-button::after,
  #menu_inc ul.open #menu-button::before {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='pt-BR'>
<head>
   <meta charset='ISO-8859-1'>
   <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='menu_style.css'>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src='menu.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <title>Teste de Menu</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='menu_inc'>
<ul>
   <li class='has-sub' id='Básico'><a href='#'><span> Básico</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub' id='Cadastros'><a href='#'><span>Cadastros</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li id='Pessoas'><a href='#'><span>Pessoas</span></a></li>
           <li id='Clientes'><a href='#'><span>Clientes</span></a></li>
           <li id='Fornecedores'><a href='#'><span>Fornecedores</span></a></li>
           <li id='Cidades'><a href='#'><span>Cidades</span></a></li>
           <li id='Bairros'><a href='#'><span>Bairros</span></a></li>
           <li id='Endereços'><a href='#'><span>Endereços</span></a></li>
           <li id='Ingredientes'><a href='#'><span>Ingredientes</span></a></li>
           <li class='last' id='Produtos'><a href='#'><span>Produtos</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub' id='Consultas'><a href='#'><span>Consultas</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li id='Pessoas'><a href='#'><span>Pessoas</span></a></li>
           <li id='Clientes'><a href='#'><span>Clientes</span></a></li>
           <li id='Fornecedores'><a href='#'><span>Fornecedores</span></a></li>
           <li id='Cidades'><a href='#'><span>Cidades</span></a></li>
           <li id='Bairros'><a href='#'><span>Bairros</span></a></li>
           <li id='Endereços'><a href='#'><span>Endereços</span></a></li>
           <li id='Ingredientes'><a href='#'><span>Ingredientes</span></a></li>
           <li class='last' id='Produtos'><a href='#'><span>Produtos</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub' id='Relatórios'><a href='#'><span>Relatórios</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>~A Inserir~</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span> Financeiro</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Cadastros</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Bancário</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Formas de Pagamento</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Taxas e Encargos</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Contas</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>A Pagar</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>A Receber</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Fluxo</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Caixa</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Bancário</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>NFe</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Emissão</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Consulta</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Relatórios</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>~A Inserir~</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
<br/>
</body>
```

---

Alterei o meu JS para um outro modelo e solucionei parte do problema, pelo momento é o suficiente! Obrigado.

Assim que finalizar as edições no mesmo deixo ele aqui para futuras consultas.

Comment: Lucas, se você encontrou a solução do seu problema coloque-a aqui como resposta e quando for liberado marque-a como resposta aceita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma regra CSS para controlar os seus sub-menus como feixados ou abertos. Eu criei a seguinte:

```
#menu_inc ul > li.has-sub > ul:not(.open){
    display:none;
}
```

<sub>A regra oculta todos os blocos de sub-menus `ul` que não tem a classe `open` de todos os `li`s que comtém a classe `has-sub`.</sub>

Crie um evento que altera a classe quando clicar no menu pai:

```
$('#menu_inc ul > li.has-sub a').click(function(event){
    // Evento padrão
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent() // Pai 'li'
          .siblings('li.has-sub').find('ul.open').each(function(index, el) { // Filho 'ul' com classe open dos Irmãos que contém classe `has-sub`
              $(this).slideUp('fast').removeClass('open');
          }); 

   $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('fast').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu_inc').prepend('<div id="indicatorContainer"><div id="pIndicator"><div id="cIndicator"></div></div></div>');
    var activeElement = $('#menu_inc>ul>li:first');

    $('#menu_inc>ul>li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        activeElement = $(this);
      }
    });

    var posLeft = activeElement.position().left;
    var elementWidth = activeElement.width();
    posLeft = posLeft + elementWidth / 2 - 6;
    if (activeElement.hasClass('has-sub')) {
      posLeft -= 6;
    }

    $('#menu_inc #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
    var element, leftPos, indicator = $('#menu_inc pIndicator');

    $("#menu_inc>ul>li").hover(function() {
      element = $(this);
      var w = element.width();
      if ($(this).hasClass('has-sub')) {
        leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 12;
      } else {
        leftPos = element.position().left + w / 2 - 6;
      }

      $('#menu_inc #pIndicator').css('left', leftPos);
    }, function() {
      $('#menu_inc #pIndicator').css('left', posLeft);
    });
    
    $('#menu_inc ul > li.has-sub a').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('fast').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $('#menu_inc>ul').prepend('<li id="menu-button"><a>Menu</a></li>');
    $("#menu-button").click(function() {
      if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
      } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#menu_inc {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  height: 44px;
  background: #b70303;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* W3C */
  width: auto;
}
#menu_inc ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
#menu_inc > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #b70303;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b70303 0%, #590000 100%);
  /* W3C */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 500;
}
#menu_inc:after,
#menu_inc > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu_inc.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#menu_inc.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#menu_inc.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu_inc > ul > #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#menu_inc ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 32px;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#menu_inc li.has-sub::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li.has-sub::after {
  /*  Seta do menu Principal*/
  right: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #FFF;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li:hover::after {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#indicatorContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#pIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transition: left .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left .25s ease;
  -o-transition: left .25s ease;
  transition: left .25s ease;
}
#cIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  top: -12px;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
#menu_inc ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#menu_inc ul ul ul {
  top: 37px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu_inc.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu_inc.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li a {
  /* Sub Menus - Fazer shadow*/
  width: 130px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}
#menu_inc.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li:hover > a {
  /* Submenu selecionado*/
  background: #8B0000;
  color: #FFF;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li:last-child > a,
#menu_inc ul ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#menu_inc > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: '';
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 30px;
}
#menu_inc.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease, right 0.2s ease;
}
#menu_inc.align-right ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
}
#menu_inc ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#menu_inc.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #menu_inc {
    width: auto;
  }
  #menu_inc.align-center ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #menu_inc.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #menu_inc ul {
    width: auto;
  }
  #menu_inc .submenuArrow,
  #menu_inc #indicatorContainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu_inc > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  #menu_inc > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #menu_inc li,
  #menu_inc > ul > li {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul,
  #menu_inc ul ul ul,
  #menu_inc ul > li:hover > ul,
  #menu_inc ul ul > li:hover > ul,
  #menu_inc.align-right ul ul,
  #menu_inc.align-right ul ul ul,
  #menu_inc.align-right ul > li:hover > ul,
  #menu_inc.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
  #menu_inc ul .has-sub::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu_inc ul li a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul li a {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 35px;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  #menu_inc.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul li:hover > a {
    background: none;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 50px;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 65px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 80px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 95px;
  }
  #menu_inc > ul > #menu-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #menu_inc #menu-button > a {
    padding: 14px 20px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul.open li,
  #menu_inc > ul.open > li {
    display: block;
  }
  #menu_inc > ul.open > li#menu-button > a {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.1);
  }
  #menu_inc ul ul::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu_inc #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  #menu_inc #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
    right: 20px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  #menu_inc ul.open #menu-button::after,
  #menu_inc ul.open #menu-button::before {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
  
  #menu_inc ul > li.has-sub > ul:not(.open){
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='pt-BR'>
<head>
   <meta charset='ISO-8859-1'>
   <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='menu_style.css'>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src='menu.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
   <title>Teste de Menu</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='menu_inc'>
<ul>
   <li class='has-sub' id='Básico'><a href='#'><span> Básico</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub' id='Cadastros'><a href='#'><span>Cadastros</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li id='Pessoas'><a href='#'><span>Pessoas</span></a></li>
           <li id='Clientes'><a href='#'><span>Clientes</span></a></li>
           <li id='Fornecedores'><a href='#'><span>Fornecedores</span></a></li>
           <li id='Cidades'><a href='#'><span>Cidades</span></a></li>
           <li id='Bairros'><a href='#'><span>Bairros</span></a></li>
           <li id='Endereços'><a href='#'><span>Endereços</span></a></li>
           <li id='Ingredientes'><a href='#'><span>Ingredientes</span></a></li>
           <li class='last' id='Produtos'><a href='#'><span>Produtos</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub' id='Consultas'><a href='#'><span>Consultas</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li id='Pessoas'><a href='#'><span>Pessoas</span></a></li>
           <li id='Clientes'><a href='#'><span>Clientes</span></a></li>
           <li id='Fornecedores'><a href='#'><span>Fornecedores</span></a></li>
           <li id='Cidades'><a href='#'><span>Cidades</span></a></li>
           <li id='Bairros'><a href='#'><span>Bairros</span></a></li>
           <li id='Endereços'><a href='#'><span>Endereços</span></a></li>
           <li id='Ingredientes'><a href='#'><span>Ingredientes</span></a></li>
           <li class='last' id='Produtos'><a href='#'><span>Produtos</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub' id='Relatórios'><a href='#'><span>Relatórios</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>~A Inserir~</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span> Financeiro</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Cadastros</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Bancário</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Formas de Pagamento</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Taxas e Encargos</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Contas</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>A Pagar</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>A Receber</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Fluxo</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Caixa</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Bancário</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>NFe</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Emissão</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Consulta</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Relatórios</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>~A Inserir~</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
<br/>
</body>
```

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente @KaduAmaral!

Muito obrigado pela explicação!

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, o que é `#menu-button`? Não encontrei esse ID no seu HTML. O que dá pra você fazer é tratar via jQuery o clique em qualquer item da classe `has-sub`. Desta forma, todos os itens principais do menu entram na jogada. Quando clicar em algo dessa classe, manda esconder todos os filhos de todos e utiliza o `$(this)` pra mostrar só os filhos de quem você clicou.

Comment: Olá, o #menu-button é adicionado via JS!

Consegui solucionar a parte de carregar tudo ao iniciar, agora preciso apenas ocultar os itens de outros menus quando eu clicar em algum outro!
Obrigado

Comment: @LucasFreitas Em outro JS que você não colocou aqui, certo? Porque nesse você não cria ele não...

Comment: Cria sim @Pasch, está quase no final do código um `prepend`...

Comment: @KaduAmaral Verdade, não tinha notado!